# Oracle sql subselect to find aggregated values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has product, date/time, and price. I split out the date/time to another column where I just split out the hour part of it. I need to find high/low/open/close of the price value by hour. I can get the high/low easy enough by doing a subselect in the select portion where I max()/min() and join the data by product & hr. I now need the open/close which will be the first record for each hour and the last record for each hour. high/low/open/close should all be the same for each record by hour.

Example result. notice how the high for all hour 7 records is 55 so that's what placed in all the hour 7 records, the low is 30 because it's the lowest of all hour 7 records, 50 is the open because the first price (sorted by date/time at 7:15) is 50. Close is the last price in the hour sorted by date/time which is 30.

```
Product, Date,            Hour, Price, High, Low, Open, Close
A,       11/12/2012 7:15, 7,    50,    55,   30,  50,   30
A,       11/12/2012 7:28, 7,    55,    55,   30,  50,   30
A,       11/12/2012 7:30, 7,    40,    55,   30,  50,   30
A,       11/12/2012 7:35, 7,    45,    55,   30,  50,   30
A,       11/12/2012 7:55, 7,    30,    55,   30,  50,   30
```

So again to recap, high/low is easy as I do subselects in the select part that query against the same table doing max/min, but not sure how to do the same thing for open/close to get the first and last records based on date/time field.

Comment: hourly updates set up for a pricing sheet ;) Anyway, Post any code you have so far please. If your incoming records to table is in order by the time. e.g. The first record for 1pm is the open. Then after 60 minutes you can check which record  (that is your close) In general every price tick has a time attached to it. So what's the matter ? :)

Comment: So this is history data not real-time so I have all the hours. I'm asking via sql how can I get the first and last for all the records in a given hour.

For example I have: select price, (select max(price) from price_tbl j where i.product = j.product and i.hr = j.hr) high from price_tbl i

I do the same for min, but how for the first and last records.if oracle had a first() and last() it would be easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this as a subquery to get the Open, replacing the product key and hour appropriately:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  Select Open
  FROM <table name>
  WHERE product = '<product key>' 
    AND hour='<the hour>'
  ORDER BY Date
) WHERE rownum = 1
```

Add this as a subquery to get the Close, replacing the product key and hour appropriately:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  Select Close
  FROM <table name>
  WHERE product = '<product key>' 
    AND hour='<the hour>' 
  ORDER BY Date desc
) WHERE rownum = 1
```

The trick here is setting ordering the result correctly and taking only the first result using `rownum = 1`.

---

Another option:

```
SELECT Open
FROM <table name>
WHERE product = '<product key>' 
  AND hour='<the hour>' 
  AND Date = (
    SELECT min(Date) 
    FROM <table name> 
    WHERE product = '<product key>' 
    AND hour='<the hour>'
    ) 

SELECT Close
FROM <table name>
WHERE product = '<product key>' 
  AND hour='<the hour>' 
  AND Date = (
    SELECT max(Date) 
    FROM <table name> 
    WHERE product = '<product key>' 
    AND hour='<the hour>'
    )
```

A drawback of this route is that these statements are not guaranteed to return a single row. Meaning if for a given product there two entries for the same hour, with the same Date value that are the min/max it will return 2 rows causing an exception when used as a sub-query.

Although that may be a good thing, instead of it arbitrarily picking a row, you will know there is a particular problem and can possibly update the query to make a more intelligent decision.

Comment: See I think rownum is calculated BEFORE the order by clause if it's in the same query and at that point it isn't guaranteed to be in any specific order. So that means I'd have to subquery that, and that doesn't work because in select statement you can't have 2 nested and use the joining of the most outer table. That's where the problem comes in.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the order by will be done first. Looking for a reference for that. In the meantime did you try running it?

Comment: You are correct, it the order by is done after the `rownum` and you have to wrap it. [ORACLE SQL ROWNUM execution order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019853/oracle-sql-rownum-execution-order). The only other option I still would still have still 2 subscribes, basically using min and max on the date column. If you want I can post it, but I think it is worse than the above.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ranking functions for this:

```
select product, datestr, hour,
       max(case when seqnum_open = 1 then price end) as Open,
       max(case when seqnum_close = 1 then price end) as Close,
       max(price) as High,
       min(price) as Low
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product, datestr, hour order by date) as seqnum_open,
             row_number() over (partition by product, datestr, hour order by date desc) as seqnum_close
      from (select t.*,
                   to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as datestr
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by product, datestr, hour
```